# Meaning of "the bents were jealous else" in Browning's Childe Roland

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry, archaic-language

From Browning's [Childe Roland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childe_Roland_to_the_Dark_Tower_Came):

> If there push’d any ragged thistle-stalk
>     Above its mates, the head was chopp’d; the bents
>     Were **jealous else**. What made those holes and rents
>   In the dock’s harsh swarth leaves, bruis’d as to baulk
>   All hope of greenness? ’T is a brute must walk
>     Pashing their life out, with a brute’s intents.

Per Wiktionary, [the "bents" are](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bent#Noun_2)

> Any of various stiff or reedy grasses.

But why were they "jealous"? I found several senses of the word, but I'm not sure. This is not helped by the fact that I'm not sure how to understand "else" here. I get something like:

> "The bents were also [protective of something]"
>
> "The bents were [enviously resentful of someone] otherwise"

This does not seem right.

Should the bents be jealous of something? All the high thistle-stalks have their heads chopped, so there's nothing to be jealous of.

Does the poet imply that it is the jealous bents that somehow led to the chopping of the thistle heads? That's odd.

---

P.S. I've just come across [this explanation that explained nothing](https://books.google.ru/books?id=uvpQAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA250&ots=OHoETwFlw7&dq=Meaning%20of%20%E2%80%9Cthe%20bents%20were%20jealous%20else%E2%80%9D&hl=ru&pg=PA250#v=onepage&q&f=false) to me:

[image]

Comment: "Otherwise the bents would be jealous" -- the low grasses would be jealous of the taller thistles. This *were* is another irrealis.

Comment: @StoneyB - Had not someone chopped the heads to level them all, the low grasses would have been jealous of the taller thistles? That's quite complex. Quite a convoluted verse. The litcrit book I quoted treats it as if all native speakers would understand this irrealis meaning right away.

Comment: I've just read it: "[it is well sometimes to half understand a poem in the same manner that we half understand the world](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Rqt1AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT5554&ots=kBHFMCbrZ-&dq=Meaning%20of%20%E2%80%9Cthe%20bents%20were%20jealous%20else%E2%80%9D&hl=ru&pg=PT5554#v=onepage&q&f=false) (G.K. Chesterton)

Comment: Just a side note, this sort of grammatical distortion is pretty common in iambic pentameter verse.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I don't think questions about archaic/poetic usages are really relevant to "learning English" (but I'm not closevoting because I'm not sure they're unquestionably Off Topic).

Comment: Though I agree that most learners have enough on their plate without trying to digest Browning, I still think that's a terrible reason to downvote such a carefully-crafted and well-researched question. +1 from me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - what skills it, if one learns English through House M.D. or through Childe Rowland? It's English still. ^_^

Comment: @CowperKettle: You had me on the ropes there! I'm not aware I've ever encountered the verb ***to skill*** before, despite being a reasonably well-read Lit Studies graduate. I had to consult the full OED to find ***to cause a distinction or difference*** (which I'm surprised to discover *isn't* flagged as "obsolete" :)

Comment: @CowperKettle: If any ragged thistle-stalk pushed up so that it was taller than its mates, its head got chopped;  the bents **would be** jealous **otherwise**.  It's not so very convoluted.  Such 'otherwises' often appear at the end of the clause, though they can head the clause too.

Comment: @J.R.♦: I would say that almost by definition you'd need to have pretty good command of *current* English (i.e. - not be a "learner") before you could contemplate trying to learn *archaic* usages like this. Unless your audience *know* that you're a competent speaker, they'll almost certainly assume you've made a mistake if you actually *use* such forms today. But as we both know, this is an area where you and I are unlikely to agree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I've tagged the question **archaic** though I was hoping to find that the tag said **archaick**.

Comment: @TRomano: Good move! At least that might alert the *average* learner that he might not want to spend time understanding or remembering the usage. But I still think it's potentially distracting / counterproductive, and mainly appeals to some here *because they can answer it*, rather than because it *needs* to be answered.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Every now and then, a question about Browning refreshes the spirit.  And there are things to be learned about the contemporary language through the study of the English of centuries past.

Comment: @TRomano: I can see both sides of the argument here, and personally I'd quite *like* to answer questions like this on ELU.  (Not least because I'd be less likely to be outclassed by the likes of you and StoneyB on ELU, since you're less active there! :) But would you want your *doctor*, for example, to be spending a lot of time researching health issues in animals, simply because humans evolved from them? If what you want to learn is current English, most of this stuff is a best peripheral to the primary task.

Comment: @Fumble - Problem is, a learner may not know something is peripheral or archaic until _after_ a question is asked and opinions start rolling in. To take your doctor analogy one step further: say you have severe abdominal pain. It could be indigestion, or maybe appendicitis, so you go to your doctor to see. He runs some tests, and it's... indigestion. Nobody wants the doc to start chiding, and ask, "Why did you come to the clinic for simple indigestion?" Similarly, learners may have a hard time discerning between little-used phrases and common idioms. I mean, if you don't know, you don't know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are many levels of learning English. This question is at a very advanced level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple allusion. The field of bents represents the oppressing mass of humanity. The head of thistle which dares to thrust itself above the mass is likened to a person who strives to rise above the mass, and who is "chopp'd," because the mass is jealous of her audacity.

As you propose, the word "else" here is equivalent to "otherwise" in modern parlance.

In modern poetry, Bob Dylan expresses the same sentiment in *It's Alright, Ma (I'm Only Bleeding)*:

> While one who sings with his tongue on fire
>   Gargles in the rat race choir
>   Bent out of shape from society's pliers
>   Cares not to come up any higher
>   But rather get you down in the hole that he's in

Answer (score 2):

"Otherwise the bents would be jealous" -- the low grasses would be jealous of the taller thistles. This **were** is another irrealis.

([Kudos to StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95174/meaning-of-the-bents-were-jealous-else-in-brownings-childe-roland#comment185797_95174))

Answer (score 2):

The word else has been transposed from where we expect it in regular speech. If we move it like so:

> If there push’d any ragged thistle-stalk above its mates, the head was chopp’d; **else** the bents were jealous

It's clearer now that **else** here means **if it was not** or **otherwise**.

To put it in plainer english:

> When a thistle dared to rise above, it's head was chopped off; if it wasn't, the thistles who were bent would be jealous (of the unchopped thistle)

There are two interpretations of this that come to mind:

1. The bent thistles want those that rise above to be chopped down, like [crabs in a bucket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_mentality) ("if I can't have it, neither can you"),  similar to what P.E. Dant said.
2. If the thistles standing tall weren't chopped down, the bent thistles might get ideas and want to stand tall themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This stanza is one of several describing what appears to be hell on earth. I'm not sure that the blades of grass represent humanity. It's possible. In the previous stanza, Nature says:

> ’Tis the Last Judgement’s fire must cure this place
>
> Calcine its clods
>   and set my prisoners free.’

This is a horrible place, at least in Roland's head. Dry grass grows like hair on a leper. Underneath the mud it looks like a dough made of blood. He sees a standing skeleton of a horse. The only way to save the prisoners of this place is for God to burn it down.

I would think these jealous bents are just cursed minions of the hell/wasteland he's traveling through -- not necessarily symbolic of anything more than that.

Comment: If you think **this** place is horrible, try _Sordello_.